# Fixing indents of a source and making it clean

Tags: r, indentation

Is there any suitable program to fix the indents of a R script already written?

For example if it is fed an script like this:

```
foo = function(x) {
a = 1
    print(a)
 }
```

It converts it to:

```
foo = function(x) {
    a = 1
    print(a)
}
```

Or better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use Yihui's [formatR](http://cran.r-project.org/package=formatR) package.

Demo with before and after:

```
R> system("cat /tmp/fex.R")
foo = function(x) {
a = 1
    print(a)
 }
R>
R> library(formatR)
R> tidy.source("/tmp/fex.R",replace.assign=TRUE)
foo <- function(x) {
    a <- 1
    print(a)
} 
R>
```

You can of course redirect to a new file using `tidy.source(..., file="NewFile.R")`

Comment: Was completely unaware of this.  Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Dirk's answer most decent editors allow you to correct the indentation of a script.  For example in RStudio if you have the script open you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to update the indentation of whatever is selected.

Comment: Yes, sure, but harder to automate and batch.  Also doesn't do the `=` to `<-` replacement.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You're right - it doesn't (but then again they didn't ask for that).  But I think your answer is more in line with what they're looking for but I figured I'd toss this in as well.  Because some people are content using RGui and to me that's just wrong and anything I can do to get them to switch to something better is a good thing in my eyes.